# How to display the bounding boxes on the image from the xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have a developed a page for tag management of images. The tags of the image are taken from an xml file.

I have tried something like:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['img_url'])) {
    $img = $_POST['img_url'];
    ?>
    <div class="container container-flex">
    <div class="left imgappend left-sec">
    <div class="img_text">
    <?php
    $link = $_POST['img_url'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    $imgpath = end($link_array);
    $ext = substr($imgpath, strrpos($imgpath, "."));
    $imgname= str_replace($ext,'',$imgpath);

    $dire="Annotated Dataset/data/";
    $file = $dire.$imgname.'.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach($xml->object as $object){ ?>

    <div class='dynamic_text <?php echo $object->name; ?>' style='display:none;'><?php echo $object->name; ?></div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <img src="<?php echo "$img"; ?>" id="scale_img">
    </div>
    <div class="right right-sec">
    <div class="input-container">
    <form action="validationxml.php" method="post" id="img_data" name="validationform">
    <span class="right-sec-text">Existing Tags in the image</span>
    <div class="exits_tags">
    <?php
    $link = $_POST['img_url'];
    $link_array = explode('/',$link);
    $imgpath = end($link_array)
    $ext = substr($imgpath, strrpos($imgpath, "."));
    $imgname= str_replace($ext,'',$imgpath);

    $dire="Annotated Dataset/data/";

    $file = $dire.$imgname.'.xml';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach($xml->object as $object){ ?>

    <div class='inputtag'>
    <i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>

            <span><?php echo $object->name; ?></span>

            <input type='hidden' name='tag_name[]' value='<?php echo $object->name; ?>'>

             <input type='hidden' name='xmin[]' value='<?php echo $object->bndbox->xmin; ?>'>

             <input type='hidden' name='ymin[]' value='<?php echo $object->bndbox->ymin; ?>'>

             <input type='hidden' name='xmax[]' value='<?php echo $object->bndbox->xmax; ?>'>

             <input type='hidden' name='ymax[]' value='<?php echo $object->bndbox->ymax; ?>'>
                            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

The above displays the image and the tags present in it. The tags are obtained from the xml file.

the xml file looks like:

```
    -<foto>
     <folder>images/fashion/MAN_BACKSTAGE_SHOW_FW18</folder>
     <scenario>Fashion</scenario>
     <filename>MAN_BACKSTAGE_SHOW_FW1833.jpg</filename>
     -<size>
      <width>1620</width>
      <height>1080</height>
      </size>
      -<object>
        <type>highlevel</type>
        <name>Tie</name>
        <created>auto</created>
       -<bndbox>
         <xmin>289</xmin>
         <ymin>0</ymin>
         <xmax>1167</xmax>
         <ymax>1059</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        </fotoinmotion>
```

The xml file holds the position of the bounding boxes of the tags. For now the the above code display the image and the tags present in it. I would like to get the bounding boxes on the image. Can someone say how to do it.

Comment: Create an extra element for each such box, and position it absolute over the image, using those four coordinates … I’m assuming those coordinates are in relation to the actual size of the image - so if you display the image at a different size than original, you would have to do some additional math here, to apply the same factor. Or you calculate the according percentage values first and use those … then it would even be responsive.

Comment: (These `max` values are probably measured from the upper left corner of the image, so if you wanted to use them for bottom/right when absolutely positioning the element, you’d have to calculate the difference between image widht / height, and those maximums. You could also position the box using top / left only, and then specify the difference between the max and min values as its width and height.)

Comment: @04FS I understand your concept , can you show me a code like implementing your concept. It will be useful for me to undestand better

Comment: Try something, and report back here, if you run into problems.